# Computer Time changes automatically

Tags: windows-7

I'm using Windows 7 and I noticed that its changing the computer time automatically often. I reset but after 3-4 days again time changes.

Can any tell me what's wrong with that? Is there any mistake in computer or any other issue?

Comment: Is your problem that it's changing the computer time _incorrectly_? If so, is it off by hours (wrong time zone) or only by a little?

Comment: Had to throw you a +1 since you were clearly sniffing at the same bone I was. I just happened to go nuts out and post for all equations ; )

Comment: @djtechie Did your issue get resolved?

Comment: @JoshCampbell Not Yet. Please check your comment.

Comment: @djtechie it is a primary yet confusing thing. Thank you for raising it to get the better answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Changes by a small amount** then that's normal. The system timer auto synchronizes itself with a time server over the internet. You can check this by doing the following:

*right click timer at lower-right corner > Adjust date/time > internet time tab > change settings > Synchronize with internet time server*

**Changes by exactly 1 or 2 hours each time**, then you may have the wrong time-zone configured, which Windows auto corrects during time server synchronizing. You can check this by doing the following:

*right click timer at lower-right corner > Adjust date/time > view time zone below clock image / select change time zone > select correct time zone from drop down and hit OK.*

**Changes randomly without pattern** then it's likely your computer is infected with the Uh Oh virus and will begin to smell like a strange cheese before exploding.

*Just kidding, it may be a CMOS issue, such as a dying battery. Easily replaced.*

Comment: Hi Josh, Can Virus be cause for this issue?

Comment: @djtechie No. In 10 years I have never heard of a virus affecting the timer. There would be no reason to. Did you already try the steps mentioned above?

Answer (score 2):

If your time zones are set correctly, and the increments are more dramatic - check to see:

1. If your router has a time-zone set correctly - as in certain cases the router can push a time adjustment to the PC (only if UAC is disabled)
2. If your machine is connected to a larger network (i.e Office network either LAN direct or VPN) as LDAP servers and Domain Controllers can push Admin defined times/time zones as they have their own clocks. I have experienced a time clock push from a DC server on many occasions.

Comment: +1 on the server time sync. I noticed the OP's profile says he's a developer. Possible he is associated with an IT company. Good catch.

Comment: Hi tgunn, its not connected to any network except internet. Its a standalone system at my home.

Comment: @tgunn thanks for the reply. I had the same router issue

Answer (score 0):

Press "FIX IT": http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/libra...10%29.aspx ;) It's working for my win7 x64 with similar problem. 
EDIT: Sorry, it doesn't work :/

Comment: "We are sorry. The page you requested cannot be found." Please fix your link. It is also advisable, where possible, to copy the gist of your linked page into your answer, this solves the problem of your answer becoming useless due to a broken link.